# How do you determine if a HtmlTableCell control is a th or td?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-table, controls

I was iterating through a table I had created and getting the first cell from each row.  Based on what type the cell was, would do different things.  Example:

```
if(cCell.type=='th' && cCell.parent.next.Cells[0].type == 'th'){
  cCell.parent.parent.controls.remove(cCell.parent);
}
```

stating, if both the current cell and the cell below it are th, then to delete current cells row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tom Ingram seems to be correct...

```
    foreach (HtmlTableRow row in MyTable.Rows)
    {
        if (row.Cells[0].TagName.ToLower() == "th")
        {
            // header.
        }
        else
        {
            // cell.
        }
    }
```

example table used...

```
<table runat="server" id="MyTable">
    <tr>
        <th>header 1</th>
        <th>header 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>cell 1</td>
        <td>cell 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no HtmlTableHeaderCell control, but [TableHeaderCell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.tableheadercell.aspx) becomes a `<th>` in the html of the page while [TableCell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.tablecell.aspx) is a `<td>`. I don't fully understand the context of your issue, but you should be able to distinguish between TableCell and TableHeaderCell with typeof(). This [list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols) of all the HtmlControls confirms that there is no type difference between `<td>` and `<th>`, both are HtmlTableCell.

I think that if you want to programmatically generate the table you are best off with the Web Controls, but if you have an already-created table, there is nothing inherently wrong with using TagName.

Answer (score 1):

If the table cells you are checking are of type System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell, you should be able to use the TagKey property ([enter link description here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.tagkey.aspx)

Then your code would be:

```
if(cCell.TagKey == HtmlTextWriterTag.Td && cCell.parent.next.Cells[0].TagKey == HtmlTextWriterTag.Th){
  cCell.parent.parent.controls.remove(cCell.parent);
}
```

Not sure what your trying to accomplish though, but I bet there are way simpler ways of doing it.